# ttk::button keep width [TCL/TK]

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

When I click on my `.tbutton4` ,I would wish when I change text by "Unlock" that the `.tbutton3` don't move. Below my code :

```
ttk::frame .toolbar

ttk::button .tbutton3 -text "Exit" -style "Toolbutton" -command {}
ttk::button .tbutton4 -text "Lock" -style "Toolbutton" -command {
if {[.tbutton4 cget -text] eq "Lock"} {
.tbutton4 config -text "Unlock"
} else {
.tbutton4 config -text "Lock"
}
}

grid .toolbar -row 0 -column 0 -sticky news

grid .tbutton4 -in .toolbar -row 0 -column 0 -padx 2 -pady 2 -sticky w
grid .tbutton3 -in .toolbar -row 0 -column 1 -padx 2 -pady 2 -sticky w
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can fix the width by setting the `-width` option of the button widget.

```
ttk::frame .toolbar

ttk::button .tbutton3 -text "Exit" -style "Toolbutton" -command {}
ttk::button .tbutton4 -text "Lock" -style "Toolbutton" -width 7 -command {
    if {[.tbutton4 cget -text] eq "Lock"} {
        .tbutton4 config -text "Unlock"
    } else {
        .tbutton4 config -text "Lock"
    }
}

grid .toolbar -sticky news

grid .tbutton4 .tbutton3 -in .toolbar -padx 2 -pady 2 -sticky w
```

This looks reasonably good to me, might need some more tweaking depending on theme etc. Using a magic number for the width is a bit iffy: once the optimal width has been established, one could possibly relate that to the string length of the longest text; e.g. `expr {[string length Unlock] + 1}`.

Documentation:
[eq (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[ttk::button (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_button.htm),
[ttk::frame (widget)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_frame.htm)

Comment: ohhhh! **-width** and this one I have forgotten ! thanks Peter